# Overriding MPNowPlayingInfoCenter while using WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, wkwebview

I am trying to create a multi-source music player with tracks coming from YouTube and Soundcloud, and I would like to override the content of MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to provide informations about the artists/releases instead of the name of the YouTube video.

Everything worked well when I used UIWebview, but for performance reasons, I had to switch to the new WKWebview and now the method I used before to set the nowPlayingInfos has no effect

Is there a way to disable the automatic mapping of the `<audio>` and `<video>` tags inside the HTML and/or to override the infos it provides with my infos?

Here's the code that I use which works on iOS 7 and worked on iOS 8 when I used UIWebview:

```
let newInfos = [
            MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: (currentPlaylist[currentPlaylistIndex] as! Track).trackName,
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: (currentPlaylist[currentPlaylistIndex] as! Track).trackArtist,
            MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: NSNumber(integer: self.getDuration()),
            MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: NSNumber(integer: self.getCurrentTime()),
            MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: NSNumber(double: self.playing ? 1.0 : 0.0),
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
        ]

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = newInfos
```

I checked that none of the variables I use are nil, and I activated my AudioSession in the AppDelegate

```
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
var error : NSError?
audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &error)
audioSession.setActive(true, error: &error)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? Just spend a day trying to find a way to override WKWebView and UIWebView providing info on the lock screen (I want to provide a UIImage and text by myself..) No success.. BTW: with IOS 8.4 and UIWebView, I can also not set the lock screen image anymore

Comment: No, I finally gave up and shipped the app without the NowPlayingInfos for iOS 8 and WKWebview
I created an issue on Apple Radar, but so far I haven't had any answers, it's been more than 3 months, and the situation is still the same in iOS 9, so I don't think that they will do anything

Comment: Hey guys! @cujo30227
Did you solve this? I have the same problem. But it's 3.5 years passed! Any solution for this?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.. still the same issue..

Answer (score 4):

Although it's impossible to override the property itself on iOS, it should be noted that changing the "title" property of the `<video>` element in JavaScript

I've achieved this behaviour with

```
var control = ...; //Create video DOM control
control.title = "Desired title";
```

Comment: how about setting the image?