# How to show playing info with MPNowPlayingInfoCenter when play audio WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, webview, wkwebview

In my react-native app I used UIWebView to show html5 audio player to user. I could successfully use MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to show playing info. But when switched to WKWebView (for performance reasons) it stopped show that info. Seems like WKWebView overrides MPNowPlayingInfoCenter. Even though I can open safari and play audio from websites and see not url but text title and can touch play/pause.

How to solve this? Please advise!

I've tried [Overriding MPNowPlayingInfoCenter while using WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029338/overriding-mpnowplayinginfocenter-while-using-wkwebview)

I need to change title, track name, image and also enable/disable buttons and track "touch" on them.

Comment: @matt It's not a duplicate!
I need to control whole Info Center. Not just "title" !

Comment: The point is that this has been asked before and no way has been found. We know this is an issue; that is well established. Your asking again contributes nothing. Hence it is a duplicate. If you need to use the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, use a different way of playing the audio.

Comment: @matt it was asked 3.5 years ago! Maybe something has changed

Comment: Well, it hasn't. Still, I'll open it back up for now.

Answer (score 0):

what is this ? html5 audio player is a web version which not work in react native i guess